# “select2” Can I key in something without choosing choices in the list

Tags: javascript, cakephp, jquery-select2

I am building a add-person website using cakePHP frame-work. I use select2 to realize ***searching and choosing function*** (ie. before you add the person, you can check whether it has already been in the list) when the user add a person's name. However, the user can't write a name without choosing a choice in the list.

Can select2 realize the function? Thanks for your answering!

Answer (score -1):

Didn't understand too much the question, please be more clear haha
but select2 is totally customizable, in the documentation you can see several options for customization:

- https://select2.github.io/options.html

And you can customize how results are matched too:

- https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher